# Can you set lifecycle policies at the folder/prefix level for Google Cloud Storage buckets?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managing-lifecycles#configexamples

I don't see any examples for what I want to do.

I'd like to have a bucket with several folders and have different expirations for each folder. Is this possible or do I just need to use many buckets?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a [MatchesPrefix](http://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#matchesprefix-suffix) condition for this.

Comment: Thanks! seems to be still unavailable :(

Comment: Thanks! Still waiting for GCP to catch up with AWS :/

Comment: Still wating ... GCP wake up!

Comment: It seems now it is possible with the prefix behaviour. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#matchesprefix-suffix